# There is a queue in Java that wait for an object when poll is called?

Tags: java, queue

I have something like this in my code:

```
worker.setObject(queue.poll());
```

I want a queue that when the `poll` method (or another one) is called, if the queue is empty, it wait until there is an object to return (not return `null`). There is some queue or method that does this.

Comment: Did you think to look at the Javadoc for the various Queues? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: A simple Google search for "java producer/consumer" would have done the trick.

Comment: +1: Asking a question that can be answered by a Google search is not against the rules of this site.

Comment: @duffymo: Have you considered the possibility that Renato wasn't familiar with the producer-consumer terminology? The Google-is-your-friend attitude is discouraged here. This question is entirely consistent with SO rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to look for a class that implements `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`. Those classes do what you want :-)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), for example.

Comment: I just tried an example with ArrayBlockingQueue and it didn't work as described, it didn't block. Then I looked in the API and saw this for method poll(): "Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty." - so, it does return null, contrary to what the questioner is asking. Then I saw the take() method ;)